# Trace all threads of a non-child process reliably and transparently with ptrace

Tags: c, linux, signals, ptrace

I am writing a small utility that needs to trace all existing threads of another running, non-child process. Besides, I would like to achieve two things in the tracer:

1. Avoid racing against the tracee process on thread creation and termination ("reliably").
2. Avoid being noticed by the real parent of the tracee process ("transparently"). For example, I do not want to trigger the shell job control.

I wonder if there exists such a way? I have tried two things but neither works fully.

Thanks!

---

### Things I tried

#### 1. trace then stop

The first one is:

- Attach to the thread group leader (thread id == process id) with `ptrace(2)`;
- Send a `SIGSTOP` to the thread with `tgkill(2)`;
- Wait for the signal-delivery stop and inject the `SIGSTOP`;
- Wait for the group stop, at which point I assume all threads of the process should stop executing;
- Walk the '/proc/PID/task' directory and attach to all the other threads;
- Resume the leader thread with some `PTRACE_*` request.

However, in this way the real parent of the tracee will be notified about the `SIGSTOP`. Here is an example program:

```c
/* tracer.c 
   compile with: cc -std=c99 -o tracer tracer.c */

#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define QUOTE(x) #x
#define STR(x) QUOTE(x)
#define die(s)                                  \
    do {                                        \
        perror("[" STR(__LINE__) "] " s);       \
        exit(1);                                \
    } while (0)

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pid_t pid = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    int opts = PTRACE_O_TRACESYSGOOD
        | PTRACE_O_TRACECLONE
        | PTRACE_O_TRACEFORK
        | PTRACE_O_TRACEVFORK;
    int status, r, sig, event;

    if (ptrace(PTRACE_SEIZE, pid, 0, 0) < 0) die("ptrace");
    if (tgkill(pid, pid, SIGSTOP) < 0) die("tgkill");
    while ((r = waitpid(pid, &status, __WALL)) > 0) {
        sig = WSTOPSIG(status);
        event = status >> 16;
        printf("[" STR(__LINE__) "] event: %3d, signal: %3d\n", event, sig);
        if (!event) {
            /* signal delivery stop */
            if (ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, pid, 0, sig) < 0) die("ptrace");
        } else if (event == PTRACE_EVENT_STOP && sig == SIGSTOP) {
            /* desired group-stop */
            if (ptrace(PTRACE_SETOPTIONS, pid, 0, opts) < 0) die("ptrace");
            break;
        } else {
            /* fallback case */
            if (ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, pid, 0, 0)) die("ptrace");
        }
    }
    if (r < 0) die("waitpid");
    /* attach to threads here... */
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, pid, 0, 0) < 0) die("ptrace");
    while (1) {
        if (waitpid(-1, &status, __WALL) < 0) {
            if (errno == ECHILD) return 0;
            die("waitpid");
        }
        sig = WSTOPSIG(status);
        event = status >> 16;
        printf("[" STR(__LINE__) "] event: %3d, signal: %3d\n", event, sig);
        if (ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, pid, 0, 0) < 0) {
            if (errno == ESRCH) return 0;
            die("ptrace");
        }
    }
}
```

On my Debian 11 system with Linux kernel 5.10.0-26-amd64, if I run in a shell (Bash in my case):

```bash
sleep 60
```

and in another shell:

```bash
./tracer <PID of sleep>
```

I can observe the desired signal delivery and group stop in the output:

```
[34] event:   0, signal:  19  <- signal delivery
[34] event: 128, signal:  19  <- group stop
[57] event:   0, signal: 133
[57] event:   0, signal: 133
...
```

However, the `sleep` process will be put into background in the shell, so it does not work "transparently".

#### 2. stop and trace

This is the approach I am currently using. Basically:

- Send a `SIGSTOP` to the thread group leader of the tracee;
- Attach to the leader thread and stop it (with `PTRACE_SEIZE` and `PTRACE_INTERRUPT`);
- Attach to all the other threads;
- Send a `SIGCONT` to the leader thread.

Honestly this is just some random pieces glued together, but it appears to work well in my experiments. I am including it here because maybe it could be a reasonable start for a proper solution, also in the hope of getting some clarifications.

I am especially confused by the signals and events seen in the tracer, as shown with the following example.

Here is a simplified program for this approach (the full version I am using in my utility program is available [here](https://github.com/pengjiz/playground/blob/6229ac09f6a9721244504a343c3841c631a9517d/system/expose/expose.c#L257-L312)):

```c
/* tracer2.c 
   compile with: cc -std=c99 -o tracer2 tracer2.c */

#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define QUOTE(x) #x
#define STR(x) QUOTE(x)
#define die(s)                                  \
    do {                                        \
        perror("[" STR(__LINE__) "] " s);       \
        exit(1);                                \
    } while (0)

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pid_t pid = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    int opts = PTRACE_O_TRACESYSGOOD
        | PTRACE_O_TRACECLONE
        | PTRACE_O_TRACEFORK
        | PTRACE_O_TRACEVFORK;
    int status, r, sig, event;

    if (tgkill(pid, pid, SIGSTOP) < 0) die("tgkill");
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_SEIZE, pid, 0, opts) < 0) die("ptrace");
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_INTERRUPT, pid, 0, 0) < 0) die ("ptrace");
    /* attach to threads here... */
    if (tgkill(pid, pid, SIGCONT) < 0) die("tgkill");
    while (1) {
        if (waitpid(-1, &status, __WALL) < 0) {
            if (errno == ECHILD) return 0;
            die("waitpid");
        }
        sig = WSTOPSIG(status);
        event = status >> 16;
        printf("[" STR(__LINE__) "] event: %3d, signal: %3d\n", event, sig);
        int req = PTRACE_SYSCALL;
        switch (event) {
        case 0:
            sig = sig == (SIGTRAP | 0x80) ? 0 : sig;
            break;
        case PTRACE_EVENT_STOP:
            switch (sig) {
            case SIGSTOP:
            case SIGTSTP:
            case SIGTTIN:
            case SIGTTOU:
                req = PTRACE_LISTEN;
            }
            sig = 0;
            break;
        default:
            sig = 0;
        }
        if (ptrace(req, pid, 0, 0) < 0) {
            if (errno == ESRCH) return 0;
            die("ptrace");
        }
    }
}
```

If I run:

```bash
./tracer2 <PID of sleep>
```

This time the shell would not be notified of the `SIGSTOP` (at least not in my experiments), but I doubt this would work reliably because there is no synchronization between the tracee and the tracer on the stopped state, and I do not know why the tracee would not notify its parent this time.

Moreover, I get the following output:

```
[41] event: 128, signal:   5  <- PTRACE_INTERRUPT
[41] event:   0, signal:  18  <- SIGCONT delivery    
[41] event:   0, signal: 133         
[41] event:   0, signal: 133
...
```

So it seems that the process has stopped before `PTRACE_INTERRUPT`. I tried a few times but the results were the same. I am not sure if that is just by coincidence. (If that is always true, then I guess I can just wait for the `PTRACE_INTERRUPT` to ensure the stopped state of all threads.)

Besides, what also confuses me is that if I did not send `SIGCONT`, I got the following output:

```
[41] event:   0, signal:  19  <- SIGSTOP delivery
[41] event: 128, signal:   5  <- PTRACE_INTERRUPT
[41] event:   0, signal: 133
[41] event:   0, signal: 133
...
```

This time we can see the `SIGSTOP`, which have never happened in my previous experiments with the `SIGCONT`. I am not sure if this is just how signals work in Linux.

Anyway, this approach appears to work well, but the behaviors are very mysterious to me, and I am not confident that this really works.

Comment: You solved the problem... Is your question _why does this work_ or _can I be confident this works?_ 'Sides, what does this program of yours intend to do with the threads?

Comment: My question is still the title: how to trace all existing threads reliably without being noticed by its real parent. The second example program worked but I doubt it would always. I am including it because maybe it could be a reasonable start for a real solution.

Comment: What I am trying to do is similar to `strace -e write=1,2 ...` but much simpler so that I can compile and run it on some strange remote machines (here is the [short description](https://github.com/pengjiz/playground/blob/6229ac09f6a9721244504a343c3841c631a9517d/system/expose/expose.c#L1-L16)). By the way, thanks for improving my question!